# Kafka streams RocksDB as an EventStore?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, event-sourcing, rocksdb

There are alot of articles about kafka and event sourcing. Most of the articles are about that kafka is not realy usefull when doing eventsourcing, because you cannot query the events just for a given aggregate id.
If you store the events in a topic, then yes this is true. This is because we need to read all the events and skip those that are not relevant.
But what about storing the events in rocksdb? Now, we can actually query all the events just for the given aggregate by using the aggregate id as prefix and do a range query in rocksdb.

Is this a good approach? I know that this will use large state and can be problematic when a rebalance occurs. But again, maybe static membership in kafka will help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams's default disk-based StateStore *is* RocksDB, so yes, this is a perfectly valid approach.

You'd [query the store via Kafka Streams APIs](https://kafka.apache.org/31/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html), not RocksDB directly, however.

> Now, we can actually query all the events just for the given aggregate by using the aggregate id as prefix

Unclear what you mean by prefix. The stores are built exclusively by Kafka record keys, not by prefixed values. However, as linked in the comments, the store does support prefix scanning, but I assume that'd be the prefix of the kafka record keys

> this will use large state and can be problematic

You can refer the [Memory Management](https://kafka.apache.org/31/documentation/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html) page on handling state and what to tune for handling its size.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. By prefix i mean prefixing the UUID of an event with the aggregate identifier. By prefixing this UUID with the aggregate identifier, we can do a range query in RocksDB. As far as i know, RocksDB can retrieve prefix-keys very efficently. For example: cust-1@xxx-xxx-1, cust-1@xxx-xxx-2. These are two events for an aggregate with id "cust-1". Everything after "@" is the uuid of the event. We can  now query all the events for cust-1 by doing a prefix scan in RocksDB (aka range query). RocksDb will then seek to that point and now we can iterate over the keys.

Comment: I'll admit to not being familiar to the internals of RocksDB, but [KeyValueStore](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.html) API does have range and prefix scanning

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams and RockDB is really good solution for a quick startup to understand the concepts but I am not sure it is good idea in the long term for the production.

My personal experience with RockDB was not that brilliant in production, if you plan to use a Key/Value database in production Apache Cassandra seems to be a much better solution.

But you are also right, querying things only over Primary Key is not that flexible, so implementing [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) does make much more sense, so you get much more flexibility for Query Side.

As a person that walked the path you plan the walk, you can find my proposed solution in my [blog](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/) :)